# How to get the core service to depend on multiple services each having its own instance of core service

Tags: angular

I've the following architecture.

[image]

How can I access separate instances of `Service E` inside `Service B,C,D`
in angular ?. At the moment same instance is returned due to `Angular DI`

**Component A:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail',
  templateUrl: './detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail.component.scss'],
})
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
      constructor(public serviceB: ServiceB, 
                  public serviceC: ServiceC, 
                  public serviceD: ServiceD) 
      {
       console.log(serviceB.printVal());
       console.log(serviceC.printVal());
       console.log(serviceD.printVal());
      }

}
```

**Service B:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ServiceB {
  constructor(private serviceE: ServiceE) {
      this.serviceE.dbString = 'str1';
  }
  printVal(){
      this.dbService.print()
  }
}
```

**Service C:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ServiceC {
  constructor(private serviceE: ServiceE) {
      this.serviceE.dbString = 'str2';
  }
  printVal(){
      this.dbService.print()
  }
}
```

**Service D:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ServiceD {
  constructor(private serviceE: ServiceE) {
      this.serviceE.dbString = 'str3';
  }
  printVal(){
      this.dbService.print()
  }
}
```

**Service E:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ServiceE {
  private dbstr: string;
  constructor(public dbService: DatabaseService) {}

  public set dbString(dbstr: string) {
      this.dbstr = dbstr;
  }

  public print() {
      console.log(this.dbstr);
  }
}
```

The result I want to get is the following.

```
str1
str2
str3
```

The result that I get right now due to DI is the following.

```
str3
str3
str3
```

Comment: You should get non-singleton services with basic DI if the `@Injectable` metadata in `ServiceE` does not declare the service as`providedIn: 'root'`.

Comment: service b,c, and d are of same module or different one? and to which module service e belong to. what is the specific usecase for which you need different instances?

Comment: Hi, I've changed the code to re-create the exact scenario. @TheHeadRush thanks for the answer. The only problem is that ServiceE also has a dependency which won't work if i remove the `providedIn` there.

Comment: Stop providing `DatabaseService` in root. If it needs to be a singleton for some reason, provide it in `app.module`.